# ERROR: data type tstzrange[] has no default operator class for access method "gist" in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, indexing, timestamp-with-timezone

I am trying to set an index to a `tstzrange[]` column in PostgreSQL 10. I created the column via the pgAdmin 4 GUI, set its name and data type as `tstzrange[]` and set it as `not null`, nothing more.

I then did a `CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;` for the database and it worked.

Then I saw in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INDEXING) that I should index the range and I do:

```
CREATE INDEX era_ac_range_idx ON era_ac USING GIST (era_ac_range);
```

...but then I get:

> ERROR:  data type tstzrange[] has no default operator class for
>   access method "gist"

which, frankly, I don't know what it actually means, or how to solve it. What should I do ?

PS, that column is currently empty, has no data yet.

Ps2, This table describes chronological eras, there is an id, the era name (eg the sixties) and the timezone range (eg 1960-1969). 
A date is inserted by the user and I want to check in which era it belongs.

Comment: If you only want to store one range, then why do you use an array of ranges?

Comment: But I dont want to store just one range. There are multiple choronological eras. Check the Ps2 part of the question I just add. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that says "and _the_ timezone range" - that's just a single range for me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, so Postgresql has two range types. `tstzrange[]` and `tstzrange`, the second one has no brackets. Should I use the second one? What is the difference? Thanks

Comment: Those aren't two types. The first is an [*array*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) (=list) of ranges, the second is a single range that contains two timestamps ("from - to"),  e.g. from 1960-09-03 18:45:01 to 1969-03-09 14:38:12 - but that's a **single** range value. But if you only want to store 1960-1969 then you probably want an `int4range`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, thanks. I just tested `tstzrange` and works fine. No, I want timestamps, the 1960-1969 was a quick example. Out of curiosity, why the `timestamp[]` array cannot get the index? Say I also wanted the `timestamp[]` to be indexed. Why it is failing? Because an index has multiple values in it? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have an array of timestamp-ranges as a single column. You can index an array with a GIN index and a range with (iirc) GIN or GiST. However, I'm not sure how an index on a column that is both would operate. I guess you could model it as an N-dimensional r-tree or some such.

I'm assuming you want to check for overlapping ranges.Could you normalise the data and have a linked table with one range in each row?

Comment: Hi Richard. Sorry but I dont get what you actually suggest I should do, I am a newbie to Postgre its indexes and its ranges. As for what I am trying to do, please check the "Ps2" part that I just added to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I got it now, I was using an array instead of a timestamp. So it could not be indexed because it was an array of timestamps?